# Не работает update-database, EF 6 Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, миграция, entity-framework-6

Пытаюсь сделать команду `update-database` через консоль NuGet, выдаёт такую ошибку, раньше такого не было, не могу понять в чём дело.

```
PM> update-database
Укажите флаг "-Verbose", чтобы отобразить инструкции SQL, применяемые к целевой базе данных.
Применение явных миграций: [201610071649530_First, 201610071746403_LongThreadName, 201610171102408_Pin, 201610201213092_AddUserContacts, 201611141916340_AddSomeIds4, 201701151850374_AddedIndexes, 201701241049187_AddedUsersToday, 201702031407171_AddFeedbackTypes, 201704090734114_AddBlog, 201705021253359_RemovedArticleUrlPart, 201705031818110_Subscriptions, 201707051658460_AddBan, 201708091510270_AddPreviewText, 201710251137452_UserLastVisit, 201711031522442_AddTracking, 201711051704220_AddTrackIndex].
Применение явной миграции: 201610071649530_First.
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Не удалось найти ресурсы, соответствующие указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре.  Проверьте правильность внедрения или связывания "Sotvorenije.Migrations.First.resources" со сборкой "Sotvorenije" во время компиляции, или убедитесь, что все необходимые сопутствующие сборки полностью подписаны и могут быть загружены.
   в System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
   в System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   в System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   в System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   в System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   в System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name)
   в Sotvorenije.Migrations.First.System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.IMigrationMetadata.get_Target() в C:\Users\Океаний\Documents\Projects\sotvorenijerep\Sotvorenije\Migrations\201610071649530_First.Designer.cs:строка 26
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.<GetTargetModel>b__2c(IMigrationMetadata mm)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.GetModel(Func`2 modelAccessor)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration.GetTargetModel()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Update>b__d()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Не удалось найти ресурсы, соответствующие указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре.  Проверьте правильность внедрения или связывания "Sotvorenije.Migrations.First.resources" со сборкой "Sotvorenije" во время компиляции, или убедитесь, что все необходимые сопутствующие сборки полностью подписаны и могут быть загружены.
```

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось что после перехода с `VS` на `Rider` и обратно пропали связи между файлами миграций, которые прописаны в файле `.csproj`, хотя возможно они пропали в результате каких-то других действий, это уже узнать вряд ли получится, но суть таже, что эти связи пропали.

- 11111_First.cs
- 11111_First.Designer.cs
- 11111_First.resx

Посмотрев как прописаны эти файлы в старых версиях проекта в `.csproj`, я по аналогии прописал их в новую версию, в моём случае хватило просто копирования записей в файле `.csproj` из старой версии в новую.

```
<Compile Include="Migrations\11111_First.cs" />
<Compile Include="Migrations\11111_First.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>11111_First.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

и

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Migrations\11111_First.resx">
    <DependentUpon>11111_First.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

И так для каждой миграции.

Миграции заработали.

Кроме того помогла сориентироваться [эта статья](http://www.devowl.net/2017/12/csharp-MissingManifestResourceException-could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-thespecified-culture-or-the-neutral-culture.html), в которой сказаны другие возможности возникновения этой ошибки.